# ORM object value as default for model field in Django 1.7

Tags: python, django

The following obviously doesn't work in Django 1.7 due to the way apps are loaded now:

```
entity = models.ForeignKey(Counterparty, default=Counterparty.objects.get(counterparty_name='A Company Ltd').pk, related_name='entity')
```

It throws a `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.` error.. Is there a way to achieve the same thing in 1.7?

Comment: Can you verify your issue addresses all these points: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-changes ?

Comment: Did you try to write something like 'default=somefunction()', and to set the value there? So it's evaluated lazily?

Answer (score 1):

Seems lazy evaluation does the trick, simply making the fetch an anonymous function that is called at runtime appears to do the trick

```
entity = models.ForeignKey(Counterparty, default=lambda: Counterparty.objects.get(counterparty_name='A Company Ltd').pk, related_name='entity')
```

Thank you schneck for the tip!

Comment: Did you get this to work? I get a `ValueError: Cannot serialize function: lambda` error when running `makemigrations` when I have a default using lambda.

Comment: Yes you're right, the lambda won't serialize (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#serializing-values). Defining a function that returns the default value in the module worked though.. Shame, the lambda approach would've been much cleaner!